# Is it undefined behaviour to cast a vector of a class containing 1 POD member to a pointer of the POD type?

Tags: c++, openal

I am using OpenAL for playing audio in an SDL2 game, and making some classes to make playing sounds easier. I have a class 'SndBuffer':

```
class SndBuffer
{
public:

    /* implementation functions */ 

private:
    // the only member of this class (this class does not have any virtual functions either). ALuint is a typedef for unsigned int.
    ALuint m_bufferId;
};
```

And another class 'SndSource' which contains an std::vector of SndBuffer's.

```
class SndSource
{
public:
    
    /* other implementation functions */

    ALuint* getBufferIds();

private:
    ALuint m_sourceId;
    bool m_sourceLoaded = false;

    std::vector<SndBuffer> m_buffers;
};
```

The definition of SndSource::getBufferIds is

```
ALuint* SndSource::getBufferIds()
{
    return reinterpret_cast<ALuint*>(m_buffers.data());
}
```

So far, the audio playback works as normal and no errors through OpenAL's alGetError(), however, is it considered undefined behaviour to cast the vector's data to ALuint*?

Comment: I think it would work for the FIRST source only (and only if static_assert(std::is_standard_layout_v<SndSource> is true). Buffers is an "array" of classes not of Ids so for the next items is wrong. So why the fixation with UB. You really should loop over all buffers and extract their Ids and put them in a vector to return. (or do something with  views in C++20)

Comment: Why not just use `m_buffers.data()->m_bufferId`

Comment: It will work as long as SndBuffer has that only bufferId member, no virtual methods and staying on the same compiler/architecture. Maybe it's not an UB, but at least it isn't good code.

Comment: @PepijnKramer I would loop over the SndBuffer’s, collect id’s, return a vector of ALuint’s (which was my previous implementation of getBufferIds), however I just thought that wasn’t a very good way of retrieving the id’s, especially multiple times per frame. It’s true I haven’t really tested if that’s a slowdown or not, I just jumped the gun with optimization. As for why the fixation with UB, from what I’ve seen, the idiomatic way of dealing with buffer id’s in OpenAL is to have a contiguous array of id’s which can be fed to API calls as a pointer, instead of looping over multiple.

Comment: Not looping is indeed good optimization (if you can do it). Memory in a vector is indeed contiguous in memory (well defined in standard), you can even rely on memory layout of an object if [is_standard_layout](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_standard_layout) trait is true. But your class has 2 members `m_sourceId` and `m_sourceLoaded`  so I would expect the vector to be layed out in memory as a mix of at least those two variables.

Comment: About UB, I think most UB is not UB but more like a programming error by NOT following the specifications as layed out in the C++ standard (out of contract use). So I would have phrased the question more like : "If I want to do this is it allowed by C++ and are my assumptions correct". But maybe I am being a bit too philosophical here :)

Comment: Most UB is the difference between correct code and code that works for me (and most people). That `reinterpret_cast<ALuint*>` appears to work because the address the buffer returns happens to be the same address of `m_bufferId`. But two things can break that: 1) the location of `m_bufferId` can be different, like when the class isn't a standard layout. 2) the pointer representation for the different types might differ. So even the address it the same the pointer will be invalid. And yes, that can happen.